# Guide for Undergraduate Research (trying to find a PDF document)

Tags: research-process, etiquette, undergraduate, email

Some time ago, a friend showed to me a 3-4 page guide for undergraduate research, which was really good. However, now I am not able to find it online anymore (and do not know anymore, who showed me the document).

In brief, I am looking for a:

- Three to five page guide / code-of-conduct for new prospective undergraduate researchers
- The guide addressed all types of aspect (documentation of results, email etiquette)
- PI was an evolutionary (?) biologist at a University of California-university (Santa Cruz possibly)

Does anyone know the guide/lab-homepage, that I am looking for?

**PS:** If anyone knows other useful guides from any other Lab homepage for new applicants (or FAQs), I would of course be interested too.

Comment: First of all, this is a shopping question to me. Second, are there some reasons you are looking for this particular guide? I searched "undergraduate research guide" on the net, tons of results returned.

Comment: Dear scaaahu, regarding the reason to look for that specific guide, I have mentioned above ("which was really good") the quality as primary criterion. Most results that come up when searching for "undergraduate research guide" are plain copy/pasting of generic life advice and not useful at all (a.k.a., "find your passion" type of advice).

Answer (score 2):

After quizzing many colleagues, I was able to find the document again. Nevertheless, thank you for the help to anyone that took the time to consider the question.

*If someone is interested:*

https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.ucsc.edu/dist/4/216/files/2019/12/Thompson-On-being-a-successful-graduate-student-v9.pdf